# Slow performance on x64 free

Tags: c++, performance, 64-bit, heap-memory, free

I have a class like this (assume all malloc's succeedes)

```
class CMyClass
{
public:
  CMyClass()
  {
  lpData = malloc(128);
  };

  ~CMyClass()
  {
  free(lpData);
  };

public:
  LPVOID lpData;
};
```

then I execute this:

```
CMyClass *lpList = new CMyClass[32768];

delete [] lpList;
```

The problem is that in x86 the code works fine and fast (some milliseconds to complete in debug and release builds) but in x64 the delete call takes about 15 seconds to free all memory.

O.S. is Win7 x64.

Hints will be appreciated.

Regards,
Mauro.

Comment: im curious, why did you choose to use malloc()/free() inside the class instead of new/delete? also, what is your compiler?

Comment: `malloc` and `free` are provided by your compiler, not by Windows. You need to tell is your compiler before we'll be able to try anything. For the record, on my machine using VS2010Sp1, I do not see this behavior.

Comment: `malloc` and `free` are NOT provided by compiler, that are in MSVCRTxx.DLL. They eventually call `HeapAlloc` (on Windows). Compiler does0n't provide functions, it just compiles. The linker just links.

Comment: internally malloc/free uses the same routines as new/delete but the problem wasn't the functions. it was the o.s. special debug heap that becomes slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible that if you are running your test app through a debugger that you are hitting some performance issue with the Windows debug heap. Add `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` to the environment settings for the debuggee (in the Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment property under Visual Studio 20xx) and see if that improves your deallocation perf.

Comment: I added the env. setting and the problem dissapeared. I will investigare further. Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this myself, using gcc 4.6.1-1 on Debian (after adding `typedef void *LPVOID`). There is no difference; both execute instantly, even without any optimization turned on.

I upped the array length to 1048576 to get a measurable runtime (0.161s), which was the same for both IA32 and AMD64. I turned on optimizations (-O3), and the time remained the same, but decreased to 0.157s. -Os (optimize for size) had the same result.

Is it possible you used different build options, like maybe you have some sort of memory access debugging enabled on AMD64?

Answer (score 1):

You are either misdiagnosing the problem or you have some heap checking turned on. I would expect so lousy performance if each malloc/free called VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree, and if that is the case, you have enabled memory debugging somehow somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try profiling both versions to see if there's anything obvious? Are the sizes in the example the actual sizes? My initial guess is that the 64-bit version needs (a lot) more memory and causes the OS to thrash which would drastically reduce performance.

Comment: Should only be ~32k more memory. Not going to cause OS thrashing with that little memory allocated.

Comment: @Billy: 32k is definitely an underestimate, each of the 32k elements will need more than one extra byte (`lpData` is larger, `malloc` metadata is larger).  Could be as much as 2MB more.  But I agree it still shouldn't be enough to cause thrashing.

Comment: @Ben: Why would malloc's metadata be larger? (The 32k number comes from `sizeof(lpdata)`)

Comment: @Billy: Because heap metadata often includes a block length (64 bits instead of 32) and/or a next block pointer (also increased to 64 bits from 32)

Comment: @Ben: Ah.. forgot about the size bit. I don't think there's a next block pointer in RtlHeap, but I could be incorrect. Most of my study of that system was dealing with what happens when memory gets free'd.

Comment: @Billy: You yourself pointed out (in a comment on the question) that `malloc` and `free` depend on the compiler, not the OS.  And so would the structure of the metadata.  Block size and next block pointer are redundant, since they differ by an offset of (current block address).  But some redundancy is desired in order to help detect heap corruption.

Comment: @Ben: AFAIK on MSVC++ malloc and free are built on top of RtlHeap. But I've not verified this myself. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same code on x64 Windows 7 SP1, x64 Release build, VC10, SP1. 
The x86 and x64 performs exactly the same way.

May you are missing something.